# Separability at a point

Tags: general-topology, mellin-transform, separable-spaces

This is from *Lectures on Forms of Higher Degree* by J. Igusa.  I don't understand the definition of "separability at a point."  It says the system of neighborhoods at $x_{\infty}$ has a countable base.  What system of neighborhoods?  Do they mean the neighborhoods of $x_{\infty}$ in the space $\overline{X}$?

[image]

Comment: It is totally unclear from the part of the text that you have shown,whether the text means that $x_{\infty}$ is a point of countable character in the space $\bar X$ or in the space $Y.$

Comment: separable in older papers/books also could mean "having a countable base"; this usage seems a remnant of that.